# Error setting UILabel text in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am quite new to Swift programming, but I am having trouble setting UILabel text in my UITableView class for individual UITableViewCell instances.

I have created a custom subclass of UITableViewCell called `PizzaTableViewCell` and a custom UITableView class called `PizzaListTableViewController`. I am trying to populate the UITableView instance with data from an array, which is being populated from an API call to my node.js server.

I have included my UITableView subclass, custom UITablveViewCell class, the struct for the data, and a link to a screenshot of the Simulator loading what I have done. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

I have verified that the data is being put in the array with no issues, as I can print the contents after the call to `fetchInventory` method. I have been able to set a single textLabel with

`cell.textLabel?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].name`

along with an image in the array with:

`cell.imageView?.image = pizzas[indexPath.row].image`

but I have 2 more labels that I need in each cell which I cannot set. I have checked my `IBOutlets` and Storyboard identifiers, and they match the code.

```swift
class PizzaListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var pizzas: [Pizza] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //title you will see on the app screen at the top of the table view
        navigationItem.title = "Drink Selection"

        tableView.register(PizzaTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Pizza")
        //tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 134
        //tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        fetchInventory { pizzas in
            guard pizzas != nil else { return }
            self.pizzas = pizzas!
            print(self.pizzas)
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
            //print(self.pizzas)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }   //end of viewDidLoad

    private func fetchInventory(completion: @escaping ([Pizza]?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request("http://127.0.0.1:4000/inventory", method: .get)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess else { return completion(nil) }
                guard let rawInventory = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]?] else { return completion(nil) }
                let inventory = rawInventory.compactMap { pizzaDict -> Pizza? in
                    var data = pizzaDict!
                    data["image"] = UIImage(named: pizzaDict!["image"] as! String)

                    //print(data)
                    //print("CHECK")
                    print("Printing each item: ", Pizza(data: data))
                    //printing all inventory successful

                    return Pizza(data: data)
                }
                completion(inventory)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func ordersButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "orders", sender: nil)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //PRINTING ROWS 0 TWICE in console
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("ROWS", pizzas.count)
        return self.pizzas.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: PizzaTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Pizza", for: indexPath) as! PizzaTableViewCell

        //cell.backgroundColor = Services.baseColor
        //cell.pizzaImageView?.image = pizzas[indexPath.row].image

        //THESE WORK BUT ARE A STATIC WAY OF SETTING THE CELLS
        //CAN ONLY SET THE SELL WITH A SINGLE TEXT LABEL FROM THE DATA ARRAY
        cell.imageView?.image = pizzas[indexPath.row].image
        cell.textLabel?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].name
        //cell.textLabel?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].description
        //cell.textLabel?.text = "$\(pizzas[indexPath.row].amount)"


//        cell.name?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].name
//        cell.imageView?.image = pizzas[indexPath.row].image
//        cell.amount?.text = "$\(pizzas[indexPath.row].amount)"
//        cell.miscellaneousText?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].description

        //print(cell.name?.text! as Any)
        print(cell.imageView as Any)

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }  //END OF

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "pizzaSegue", sender: self.pizzas[indexPath.row] as Pizza)
    }  //END OF override func tableView

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "pizzaSegue" {
            guard let vc = segue.destination as? PizzaViewController else { return }
            vc.pizza = sender as? Pizza
        }
    }  //END OF override preppare func

}
```

```swift
class PizzaListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var pizzas: [Pizza] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //title you will see on the app screen at the top of the table view
        navigationItem.title = "Drink Selection"

        tableView.register(PizzaTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Pizza")
        //tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 134
        //tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        fetchInventory { pizzas in
            guard pizzas != nil else { return }
            self.pizzas = pizzas!
            print(self.pizzas)
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
            //print(self.pizzas)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }   //end of viewDidLoad

    private func fetchInventory(completion: @escaping ([Pizza]?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request("http://127.0.0.1:4000/inventory", method: .get)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess else { return completion(nil) }
                guard let rawInventory = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]?] else { return completion(nil) }
                let inventory = rawInventory.compactMap { pizzaDict -> Pizza? in
                    var data = pizzaDict!
                    data["image"] = UIImage(named: pizzaDict!["image"] as! String)

                    //print(data)
                    //print("CHECK")
                    print("Printing each item: ", Pizza(data: data))
                    //printing all inventory successful

                    return Pizza(data: data)
                }
                completion(inventory)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func ordersButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "orders", sender: nil)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //PRINTING ROWS 0 TWICE in console
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("ROWS", pizzas.count)
        return self.pizzas.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: PizzaTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Pizza", for: indexPath) as! PizzaTableViewCell

        //cell.backgroundColor = Services.baseColor
        //cell.pizzaImageView?.image = pizzas[indexPath.row].image

        //THESE WORK BUT ARE A STATIC WAY OF SETTING THE CELLS
        //CAN ONLY SET THE SELL WITH A SINGLE TEXT LABEL FROM THE DATA ARRAY
        cell.imageView?.image = pizzas[indexPath.row].image
        cell.textLabel?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].name
        //cell.textLabel?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].description
        //cell.textLabel?.text = "$\(pizzas[indexPath.row].amount)"


//        cell.name?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].name
//        cell.imageView?.image = pizzas[indexPath.row].image
//        cell.amount?.text = "$\(pizzas[indexPath.row].amount)"
//        cell.miscellaneousText?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].description

        //print(cell.name?.text! as Any)
        print(cell.imageView as Any)

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }  //END OF

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "pizzaSegue", sender: self.pizzas[indexPath.row] as Pizza)
    }  //END OF override func tableView

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "pizzaSegue" {
            guard let vc = segue.destination as? PizzaViewController else { return }
            vc.pizza = sender as? Pizza
        }
    }  //END OF override preppare func

}
```

```swift
struct Pizza {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let amount: Float
    //let amount: String
    let image: UIImage

    init(data: [String: Any]) {

        //print("CHECK:: pizza.swift")

        self.id = data["id"] as! String
        self.name = data["name"] as! String

//        self.amount = data["amount"] as! Float
        self.amount = ((data["amount"] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue)!


        self.description = data["description"] as! String
        self.image = data["image"] as! UIImage
    }

}
```

As noted above, I have been able to print the contents of the data array with beer names, pictures, descriptions and etc. I have tried to print to console

`print(cell.name?.text)`

after setting

`cell.name?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].name`

but it prints `nil` and this is a problem. I have been stuck with this for about 2 weeks!

IBOutlets screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You need to have a custom table cell with more than one label.

Comment: You are setting `cell.imageView?.image` and `cell.textLabel?.text`, but those are default elements of a default table view cell. If you're using a custom designed cell, you need to give those elements different `IBOutlet` names and set ***those*** values, such as `cell.myTextLabel?.text`

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I do indeed have a custom table cell and it has 3 text labels and one UI Image. The custom cell class is called PizzaTableViewCell and I have set 4 IBOutlets and connected them to the storyboard.                                  
  ```swift  @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pizzaImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var amount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var miscellaneousText: UILabel! ```

Comment: @DonMag I have indeed tried to set the labels with that notation. If you look in the code above I have that way commented out.                                    ```cell.name?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].name
cell.imageView?.image = pizzas[indexPath.row].image
cell.amount?.text = "$\(pizzas[indexPath.row].amount)"
cell.miscellaneousText?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].description``` .  cell.name is referring to the IBOutlet I have set in the custom table view cell class, here is a link to that code.  https://i.imgur.com/EDG9Ogt.png

Comment: why do you comment out cell.miscellaneousText?.text ? what is the error ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri When I try and set the text label that way the tableView only loads the images in each of the cells. None of the labels load in the cells. I also print the contents of cell. ```print(cell.miscellaneousText?.text)``` and when I do each of the labels are nil but the contents of  ```print(cell.imageView as Any)```  are ```Optional(<UIImageView: 0x7ff61244ac80; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000021df020>>)``` .

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Im really at a loss because I cannot understand why the data will set properly to the cell.name , cell.amount, and cell.miscellaneous when I have proved the data is properly coming across from the API call to my data array.

Comment: try removing  tableView.register(PizzaTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Pizza")

Comment: please refer this for sample : https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

Comment: Sorry, can't help but wonder if you have actually assigned `PizzaListTableViewController` as the subclass for your tableview controller in the storyboard. Right now it says `RootViewController` and it doesn't look like it has a class assigned to it as the others do in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I think i found your Problem, let me explain

What you are doing here is you have a custom `UITableViewCell` defined in the `Storyboard` in a Controller named "Root View Controller" which is not your `PizzaListTableViewController` to put it simply

And as you said you have absolutely no issue regarding the `IBOutlets`

Now when you say

```
tableView.register(PizzaTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Pizza")
```

In Your `PizzaListTableViewController` you are not linking it with the UI of the cell rather just the Code (This is only used when there is no xib of the cell)

*Now what you can do to solve this*

**Solution # 1**

- Move/Copy your UI of the `PizzaTableViewCell` to `PizzaListTableViewController` in the storyboard from your "Root View Controller"
- Make sure you add a `Reuse Identifier` in the Attribute Inspector of the cell in the storyboard
- remove `tableView.register(PizzaTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Pizza")` this wont give you an error this time as it will automatically get register
- Make sure all the `IBOutlets` are connected

**Solution #  2**

create a separate `Nib` (`xib`) of the cell 
and now you have to register the cell here like

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PizzaTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PizzaCell")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried your second solution and the app crashes when the tableView is getting loaded. I am getting this error: ```Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle <...DrinkupClient.app> (loaded)' with name 'DrinkTableViewCell''```. I have changed the name of the identifier to "cell" and updates in interface builder and in the code.

Comment: @AustinGriffith For the second one you have to create a `PizzaTableViewCell.xib` file.

Comment: I am also trying to understand the first part of your solution #1. I dont understand what you mean by "Move/Copy your UI of the PizzaTableViewCell to PizzaListTableViewController in the storyboard from your "Root View Controller"". I have taken out the line ```tableView.register(...)``` but this crashes the app ```Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'```

Comment: Yes you should get the error if you didnt copy your `Copy your UI cell in the story board` to your PizzaListTableViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cell.name?.text = ...
cell.amount?.text = ...
cell.miscellaneousText?.text = ...
cell.pizzaImageView?.image = ...
```

If it still does not work then make sure your cell and your outlets are not null when setting its value. Hope it helps !

Comment: @DuyNguyen I have tried this already as noted in my code above. I have it commented out right now because when using this method my table view loads blank cells with no labels nor image. The only way I have been able to get a single textLabel to load and the images to load in each cell is with this notation:  ```cell.imageView?.image = pizzas[indexPath.row].image
        cell.textLabel?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].name``` .  If I try and add another label such as ```cell.textLabel?.text = pizzas[indexPath.row].description``` The second assignment overrides the first and only one loads.

Comment: @AustinGriffith try comment out this line of code `tableView.register(PizzaTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Pizza")`

Comment: @DuyNguyen If I remove that line of code I am faced with this error in the console. ```*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier PizzaCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'``` I know I have put the cell Identifier in the Interface builder as well so I am very unsure why I get this.

Comment: @AustinGriffith try change `Pizza` to `PizzaCell` in this line `let cell: PizzaTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Pizza", for: indexPath) as! PizzaTableViewCell`

I assume `PizzaCell` is set as the cell identifier in the IB, if you do not register class for tableview, then it look for the cell from IB which has the exact cell identifier

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There is something definitely strange going on with your setup.
If you try to name the IBOutlets with the same name as the UITableViewCell default property it'll throw an error. The fact that you were able to set those names and build successfully is strange.

From the screenshot above you can see what happens when I attempted to do this.

Comment: Would you add a screenshot of the Identity Inspector for your custom tableviewcell ?

Comment: I have renamed the outlets to be something different from the labels and such in Interface builder, I dont think they were ever the same!

Comment: Here is a link to the screenshot of Identity Inspector for my custom tableviewcell. In my custom cell class I have renamed the IBOutlets to the following: ```@IBOutlet weak var cellName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellAmount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!```  These are the names you will see in the interface builder -> Identity Inspector for the cell (https://i.imgur.com/Da34abs.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure your Table View Controller class is set in the storyboard.

[image]

Make sure your Table View Cell class is set in the storyboard.

[image]

Make sure that all your outlets are properly connected.

[image]

Make sure your Table View Cell Identifier is provided in the storyboard.

[image]

My Table View Controller Subclass

[image]

My Table View Cell Subclass

**cell.imageView?.image** and **cell.textLabel?.text** are optional properties of the table view itself. They are not the properties of the custom cell that you designed.

You use **tableView.register(PizzaTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Pizza")** when you have designed a table view cell in XIB. But as you have designed the cell in the storyboard itself you should set the cell reuse identifier and cell class in the storyboard.

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed pictures. I have actually gone through those exact steps a handful of times. I know that cell.imageView?.image and cell.textLabel?.text are optional properties of the table view but even trying to set the labels and images with my custom class, the table view just loads as blank, nothing appears but the app doesn't crash, so I am still confused why I cannot set them and see results in simulator. The values of  ```print(cell.cellName?.text as Any)``` still continue to print as nil in the console for all cell.cellAmount, cell.cellDescription and etc

Comment: Can I have an image of your UITableViewCell subclass ?  If cellName is an outlet in your cell class it should not be optional. Please remove the tableView.register() code from your view controller.

Comment: @ArijitiSarkar I have linked here to a git gist as I have changed up the code a bit. (https://gist.github.com/Austin-Griffith/a93ae2ed060d77528f9c51f54aa20e57) As of right now in my code if I remove the tableView.register() line in the viewDidLoad method, the app crashes once it get to loading the tableView. In my UITableViewCell custom class I do not have the cell IBOutlets set as optionals. The way I have it working right now is using the cell style: subtitle and setting the cells default texLabel, detailTextLabel and UIImage with the data in my array.